# Test if function returns input-length output

Tags: r

I am defining an S4 function class to ensure the length of the output equals the length of the input (sort of one-to-one, but not in the calculus sense), e.g.

```
EqLenOut <- setClass("EqLenOut", contains = "function")
.EqLenOut.validity <- function(object) {
  msg <- NULL
  if (length(formals(object)) > 1) {
    msg <- c(msg, "EqLenOut must only have one argument.")
  }
  tst1 <- length(object(1:5)) != 5
  tst2 <- length(object(1:6)) != 6
  if (tst1 || tst2) {
    msg <- c(msg, "EqLenOut output length must equal input length.")
  }
  msg
}
S4Vectors::setValidity2("EqLenOut", method = .EqLenOut.validity)
```

It works, but it is imperfect to test the function for two arbitrary numeric inputs. In my particular case, I will also be requiring numeric inputs & outputs. However, it would be nice to setup a general "equal-output" class that both equal output numeric or non-numeric functions could contain.

**How to best (rigorously & efficiently) test if a function output length equals the input length, regardless of the input/output?**

*If there is a name for classes of functions that take an n-length input vector and return an n-length output vector, I would love to make the question title more specific.*